# How to include escape char in Python string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to build a string dynamically with the following code

```py
output = "".join(["network", "\", "account"])
```

The escaped result should be something like `network\account`

How can do this in Python3 without running into this errors

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
"".join(["network", "\", "account"])
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If this is about file system paths, you might consider using os.path.join or similiar tools from the os library - this will help you keep things tidy in case of operating system switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the backslash:

```
output = "".join(["network", "\\", "account"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Raw strings is another way (someone already posted an answer using an escape character).

Precede the quotes with an r:

```
r'network\account
```

Edit:

I realise that this doesn't actually work with your example using a single backslash,

I had posted:

```
output = "".join(["network", r"\", "account"])
```

but according to Python docs.

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the
>   backslash remains in the result; for example, r"\"" is a valid string
>   literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote;
>   r"\" is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an
>   odd number of backslashes). **Specifically, a raw literal cannot end in
>   a single backslash** (since the backslash would escape the following
>   quote character).

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=raw%20strings

Comment: Worked in raw `r'network\account` but failed when used in join. Going with @sami-rouhe answer instead for this implementation

Comment: Yes, I realised that, and posed a link to the python docs explaining why. I learned something myself today. Raw strings can still be handy if its not just a single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

In Python strings, the backslash "\" is a special character, also called the "escape" character, so use '\\' for "escape" character

```
output = "".join(["network", "\\", "account"])
```